# Vector images get distorted in alpha test on play store

Tags: android, google-play, vector-graphics

I published my application in alpha testing channel of Google Play Store and the issue is that all the vector images used in the app get distorted in pre-lollipop devices and that too in different ways every time I open the app. I minifyed my app. Any help will be really appreciated. Why is this happening?

[image: When I opened my app first time]

[image: When I opened my app first time]

Answer (score 0):

in what way are they distorted?

make sure you add this line to the gradle file

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Comment: I am alreaady using vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true. I have added screenshots of my app.